# Excel: select a changing range from a column and copy it

Tags: excel

I have a very long column( 50000 rows) and I want select a range (sample) of cells (number of rows)  in order to apply certain calculations. You don't have to worry about the calculation formula. Here I just need help on how to do the sampling. The range(sample) should be changing based on window size. The window size is a number I can choose .i.e such in the example below I chose the window size to be 4.  In other words, I need to have samples, and these samples are based on selected number of rows of the long column. The size(number of rows) for all of the samples will be equal to the window size. However, each sample is shifted by one from the main column. Now, the samples should be in seperate columns , and thats why I need to copy the selection in each sample in its required column.For illustration purpose, assume the below example:
let assume the window size( number of rows)=4

```
test
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
 7
 8
 9
 10
```

The expected output should be :

```
main col sample1 sample2 sample3  sample4 sample5 sample6 
 1         1       2         3         4       5     6  
 2         2       3         4         5       6     7  
 3         3       4         5         6       7     8
 4         4       5         6         7       8     9
 5    
 6 
 7 
 8
 9
 10
```

each sample of size 4 rows , however, each new sample shifs by 1 from the main column. Note we get 6 samples to cover the whole number of rows in the main column. What basically should be done: sample1 will be from row1-to-row4 from the main col. Now, sample2 will be 4 values, however, from row2-to-row5, from the main column. sample3 will be 4 values, from row3-to-row6, and so on until we cover the whole range of the main column. So there are two main process, selection and copy of selection.

I have tried to use the offset and other logical function ... but it didn't work. I don't want to use Macros or VBA... Is there are any built in functions to solve the problem.?

Comment: Your question is unclear.  There may be a formula-based approach to your question - such as using row() and column() together with mod(), but it's difficult to tell without more details of what the formulas would need to calculate.

Comment: I agree with @TimWilliams, the question is somewhat unclear, also as far as I know excel formulas are completely unaware of anything to do with the state of the UI, e.g. size, position, visibility status, screen resolution, etc. This issue sounds like it will need VBA, but I will not discount some very, very, creative use of excel formulas.

Comment: @Eng.Mohd are you trying to do some MatLab like matrix formula in Excel? If that's the case you need to provide the proper logic behind your actions that you are trying to achieve.. :)

Comment: Could you give some example of what input looks like and what desired output would look like?  Like others, I don't fully understand what you're getting at.

Comment: @ Dean MacGregor , @ bonCodigo  , @TheGreatCO, @ Tim Williams .... Thanks for the reply... I update the question.

Comment: You want the number of sample columns to be dynamic and the only choice variable is size of the sample?  Is 'main col' from your output intentionally the same as 'test' from your input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically a variation of a range transpose. Use the formula:

```
=INDEX($A:$A,COLUMN()+ROW()-2,1)
```

Then just copy to whatever window size you want. It will automatically move down the main column by one row for every column over it is. The result looks like this (you are responsible for copying the formula to the right size):

[image: Result]

Bonus, you can automate the column header "Sample N" with:

```
="Sample " & COLUMN()-1
```